# how to create fluid simulation in glass?

Tags: rendering, animation, fluid-simulation, eevee-render-engine

[image]

how to create fluid simulation in glass?

Comment: what exactly is the problem you're having? have you tried searching for a tutorial or other questions here?

Answer (score -1):

There is a video you should be able to figure out the minor  changes but other wise there.
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=YgwKPP2ZEjI